Aligning vertical scroll positions of related parts between main block and gutter
I am rendering something like scriptural verse numbers. At the moment I have text something like this:

1 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.  2 And the earth
was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep.
And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
3 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.  4 And God saw
the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.
5  And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the
evening and the morning were the
first day.

The verse numbers are hyperlinks, and I want those always available; I also want users to be able to distinguish the verses. But I need a more subtle approach than throwing the numbers in the reader's face. I also want to prevent the numbers from showing up when the user copies text. (not critical.)
My plan is to add a gutter to the left of the text and put the numbers in there, aligned with the start of the verses (like the line numbers in a code editor):

1       In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.   And the earth
2       was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep.
         And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
3       And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.  And God saw
4       the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.
5       And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the
         evening and the morning were the first day.

If the user hovers on a verse number, say, 4, then the corresponding verse itself is highlighted:

1       In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.   And the earth
2       was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep.
         And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
3       And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.  And God saw
4     the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.
5       And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the
         evening and the morning were the first day.

But I don't have a clue of how to go about that. I have complete control of the HTML/CSS/JS, although I was hoping to do it without JS if that's possible.  There are plenty of techniques for doing this to add line numbers, but I can't see how to convert them to handle the scenario where a line number matches with a verse that might be on multiple lines, or share a line with part of another verse.
How can I implement this?
Edit: I have created a mocked-up version of what I would like to be able to generate.  The HTML and (large) CSS are from TiddlyWiki.  You can see this as an attempt to improve on two different versions with different designs.
The discussion on this overall project is on talk.tiddlywiki.com, if you're interested.  An important point I realized that I forgot in the discussion above is that while I'm in charge of the markup, it's dynamic markup based on Book/Chapter/Verse data.  I don't get to hardcode things as I do in this mock-up.

Could you show us the HTML structure you are using now, how are those hyperlinks embedded in the text and what CSS is applied?

Although most of this can be done in HTML/CSS I think a small amount of JS will be needed to get the vertical spacing correct. Is that acceptable?

@AHaworth: I can create the HTML/CSS as needed. although I always prefer something relatively semantic.  I can use JS, and I consider myself quite competent in it, but the environment will make JS more difficult than usual.

Really, opinion-based?  A question asking how to achieve a certain effect with HTML/CSS is opinion-based?  I've removed two vaguely opinion-related phrases/sentences and am hoping others will vote to reopen. ("I would certainly entertain other approaches..." and "Any alternative approaches you think worth considering?")

Voted to reopen, I suspect the closers were concentrating on the q of whether the suggested layout was good or whether there were others that might be ‘better’ rather than whether it was an interesting technical question (which it is).

@AHaworth I don't think so. "Not an interesting question" is not a valid close vote reason, so one should not assume that is why anyone closes questions at all. I can see why voters went with 'opinion-based' closure (opinion-based queries were strewn throughout the question body). I think there is an objective question in there, but it takes a lot of effort to reveal it.

Something that's blocking me from casting a reopen vote is what you mean by "There are plenty of techniques for doing this to add line numbers, but that's fairly mechanical; I can't see how to convert them to handle this.". The first link you provided there shows exactly how to add line numbers and prevent them from being copied when a user copies the text. So do you have a problem with implementing that or no? Also, why does it being "mechanical" (what does that mean?) cause a problem? We aren't here to cater to preferences; we're here to answer objective questions/solve objective problems.

Your request of hovering over a line number and having it hover the text is a separate question from showing non-copyable line numbers, and also arguably a reason to keep the question closed, since questions on Stack overflow should ask one thing. If the code demo you linked for adding non-copyable line numbers is enough to solve that problem for you, then it's OK to ask instead about getting the hover functionality working, but not both (don't include phrasing about having difficulty with inserting line numbers).

@TylerH: By "mechanical", I meant that adding line numbers doesn't really require us to have to know anything about the data/markup.  For my case the numbers are (presumably) part of the markup, and their position in the gutter is not a simple feature of putting them on sequential lines; the approximate alignment with the start of the verse is critical.  (Approximate because sometimes multiple verses start on the same line, and there would have to be an adjustment for that.

@TylerH: I think of the question as, "How could I achieve this layout subject to these constraints?"  But the text-copying point is far less important than laying out of the numbers into the gutter with the hover-to-highlight behavior. I've struck out the line about it in the post.  Also thank you for your edit.  Definitely cleaner afterward!

@ScottSauyet Thanks for the additional clarification. I've made another minor adjustment to the question and cast a reopen vote.

I don’t entirely understand your newly added mocked up version. e.g. 31 being next to a blank line. Does the last sentence have a verse number? [and there are some instances of it looking as though the first sentence in a ‘verse’ doesn’t have a number, or can verses be split over ‘paragraphs’?]

@AHaworth: Hmm, I've only tested in Brave, Chrome, and Firefox, but in all of them the verse numbers align with their text -- usually the start of the line, but sometimes the next line if two verses start on the same line.  In any case, that's the goal, even if the mockup doesn't show it for you.  And no, verses never split across paragraphs.

While the verse numbering and positioning and the linking and the highlighting can be done using HTML/CSS only, to get the vertical spacing a small amount of JS will be needed as currently CSS does not allow counter values to be used in calculations.
[Actually, this is not strictly true, a humungous amount of CSS, using nth-child and :has would be possible, but it would be somewhat impractical for anything other than a very few verses].
To keep the sort of spacing you have in the text you show I have inserted paragraphs elements.


const paras = document.querySelectorAll('.verses p');
paras.forEach((p) => {
  const verses = p.querySelectorAll('a');
  p.style.setProperty('--numverses', verses.length);
  verses.forEach((verse, i) => {
    verse.style.setProperty('--i', i);
  });
})
.verses {
  counter-reset: verseNum;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.verses p {
  --numverses: 0;
  min-height: calc(var(--numverses) * 1em);
}

.verses p>a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: calc(var(--i) * 16px);
  right: -0.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 2em;
}

.verses p>a::before {
  counter-increment: verseNum;
  content: counter(verseNum);
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 2em;
}

a:hover+span {
  background: yellow;
}
<div class="verses">
  <p>
    <a href="#"></a><span> In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.</span>
    <a href="#"></a><span> And the earth
was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep.
And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.

</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#"></a><span> And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.</span>
    <a href="#"></a><span> And God saw
the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.</span>
    <a href="#"></a><span>
 And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the
evening and the morning were the first day.</span>
  </p>
</div>




Thank you.  I will play with this, especially to see how it works with longer passages and longer verses.  There's something very clever in here, but I think my example might have been misleading.  Although the verse numbers would be sequential, there's no guarantee that they would start with 1.  I was assuming that the actual numbers would be part of the markup; that's not essential, but I do need to be able to specify at least the first one and not simply derive it from counters.

You can have them as part of the markup by putting them say into data-versenum attributes instead of doing the calculation. Incidentally, I think more JS will be needed to find the correct vertical positions of varying length verses.

Yes.  That "more JS" here is what I was hoping to avoid, but I don't think it's avoidable.  Thank you.

This does not meet OP's requirement that the text be copied (because it's not selectable). Or at least, selecting is quite buggy: You have to start your selection from outside the entire paragraph and then drag over to select the part you want. You can't hover over a phrase and select that phrase at the same time. (Note, I'm happy to remove my downvote if that issue can be fixed, or if OP updates to say they don't care about copying it or are OK with JS-powered copying via a "copy" button or similar.)

@TylerH: Oh, I hadn't noticed that.  You're right that this is a problem.  I really don't want any hover effect on the main text, only on the hyperlinks.  (Although my latest temporary solution--because I couldn't get close to what I want--hides the verse number altogether except for the title tooltip and simply highlights the verse on hover.  (Also, when you click, it opens the verse on its own.)  Older versions showed the line number inline.  Hmm.

@TylerH thanks for spotting the errors. I've changed the code so the a elements come outside the span elements. The verses are not highlightable from within themselves now (needed a to have definite width) and the verses are copiable. Now all we need is bit of JS to make sure the verse numbers are at the right vertical level (as close to the start of the relevant verse vertical position as possible). Pity it needs to be JS but I think it does.

Thank you.  That's a great improvement!  I'm pretty sure you're right, though, about needing JS for this.  I'm still fiddling, but thank you for the help!
